# Importing a png image to use as menu background but upon running, a blank screen is shown?

Tags: java, png

I'm making an adaptation of snake following a youtube tutorial in Java and I've had an issue in creating the menu. I've imported my PNG image to be used as the background, however when I run it, the image is blank, any ideas why?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class snakeCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
private final int BOX_HEIGHT = 15;
private final int BOX_WIDTH = 15;
private final int GRID_HEIGHT = 25;
private final int GRID_WIDTH = 25;

private LinkedList<Point> snake;
private Point fruit;
private int direction = Direction.NO_DIRECTION;

private Thread runThread; //allows us to run in the background
private int score = 0;
private String highScore = "";

private Image menuImage = null;
private boolean isInMenu = true;

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if (runThread == null)
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.addKeyListener(this);  
        runThread = new Thread(this);
        runThread.start();
    }
    if (isInMenu)
    {
        DrawMenu(g);
        //draw menu
    }
    else
    {
        if (snake == null)
        {
        snake = new LinkedList<Point>();
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        PlaceFruit();
        }
        if (highScore.equals(""))
        {
            highScore = this.GetHighScore();
        }
        DrawSnake(g);
        DrawFruit(g);
        DrawGrid(g);
        DrawScore(g);
        //draw everything else
    }
}

public void DrawMenu(Graphics g)
{
    if (this.menuImage == null)
    {
    Image menuImage = null;
    try
    {
        URL imagePath = snakeCanvas.class.getResource("snakeMenu.png");
        this.menuImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.drawImage(menuImage, 0, 0, 648, 480, this);
    }
}

public void update(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics offScreenGraphics;
    BufferedImage offscreen = null;
    Dimension d= this.getSize();

    offscreen = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    offScreenGraphics = offscreen.getGraphics();
    offScreenGraphics.setColor(this.getBackground());
    offScreenGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    offScreenGraphics.setColor(this.getForeground());
    paint(offScreenGraphics);

    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
}

public void GenerateDefaultSnake()
{
    score = 0;
    snake.clear();

    snake.add(new Point (0,2));
    snake.add(new Point(0,1));
    snake.add(new Point(0,0));
    direction = Direction.NO_DIRECTION;
}

public void Move() //adds a new 'block' at front of snake, deleting the back 'block' to create movement
{
    Point head = snake.peekFirst();  //grab the first item with no problems
    Point newPoint = head;
    switch (direction) {
    case Direction.NORTH:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1); //vector of -j
        break;
    case Direction.SOUTH:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);
        break;
    case Direction.WEST:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x - 1, head.y);
        break;
    case Direction.EAST:
        newPoint = new Point (head.x + 1, head.y);
        break;  
    }


    snake.remove(snake.peekLast()); //delete the last block

    if (newPoint.equals(fruit))
    {
        //the snake hits the fruit
        score+=10;
        Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone(); //creating the end piece upon eating fruit

        switch (direction) {
        case Direction.NORTH:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1); //vector of -j
            break;
        case Direction.SOUTH:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);
            break;
        case Direction.WEST:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x - 1, head.y);
            break;
        case Direction.EAST:
            newPoint = new Point (head.x + 1, head.y);
            break;
        }
        //the movement upon eating fruit
        snake.push(addPoint);
        PlaceFruit();

    }
    else if (newPoint.x < 0 || newPoint.x > (GRID_WIDTH - 1))
    {
        //snake has gone out of bounds - reset game
        CheckScore();
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (newPoint.y < 0 || newPoint.y > (GRID_HEIGHT - 1))
    {
        //snake has gone out of bounds - reset game
        CheckScore();
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (snake.contains(newPoint))
    {
        //running into your tail - reset game
        CheckScore();
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }

    snake.push(newPoint);
}

public void DrawScore(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Score: " + score, 0, BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT + 15);
    g.drawString("Highscore:" + highScore, 0, BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT + 30);
}

public void CheckScore()
{
    if (highScore.equals(""))
        return;

    if (score > Integer.parseInt((highScore.split(":")[1])))
    {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New highscore. Enter your name!");
        highScore = name + ":" + score;

        File scoreFile = new File("highscore.dat");
        if (!scoreFile.exists())
        {

            try {
                scoreFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileWriter writeFile = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writeFile = new FileWriter(scoreFile);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
            writer.write(this.highScore);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            try
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}

public void DrawGrid(Graphics g)
{
    //drawing the outside rectangle
    g.drawRect(0, 0, GRID_WIDTH * BOX_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT * BOX_HEIGHT);
    //drawing the vertical lines
    for (int x = BOX_WIDTH; x < GRID_WIDTH * BOX_WIDTH; x+=BOX_WIDTH)
    {
        g.drawLine(x, 0, x, BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT);
    }
    //drawing the horizontal lines
    for (int y = BOX_HEIGHT; y < GRID_HEIGHT * BOX_HEIGHT; y+=BOX_HEIGHT)
    {
        g.drawLine(0,  y,  GRID_WIDTH * BOX_WIDTH, y);
    }
}

public void DrawSnake(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    for (Point p : snake)
    {
        g.fillRect(p.x * BOX_WIDTH, p.y * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void DrawFruit(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(fruit.x * BOX_WIDTH, fruit.y * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void PlaceFruit()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomX = rand.nextInt(GRID_WIDTH);
    int randomY = rand.nextInt(GRID_HEIGHT);
    Point randomPoint = new Point(randomX, randomY);
    while (snake.contains(randomPoint))  //If the fruit happens to spawn on the snake, it will change position
    {
        randomX= rand.nextInt(GRID_WIDTH);
        randomY= rand.nextInt(GRID_HEIGHT);
        randomPoint = new Point(randomX, randomY);
    }
    fruit = randomPoint;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true)
    {
        repaint(); 
        //runs indefinitely (CONSTANTLY LOOPS)
        if (!isInMenu)
            Move();

                     //Draws grid, snake and fruit

        //buffer to slow down the snake
        try
        {
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(100);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public String GetHighScore()
{
    FileReader readFile = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
    readFile = new FileReader("highscore.dat");
    reader = new BufferedReader(readFile);
    return reader.readLine();

}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Nobody:0";
    }
    finally
    {
        try{
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        if (direction != Direction.SOUTH)
            direction = Direction.NORTH;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        if (direction != Direction.NORTH)
            direction = Direction.SOUTH;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        if (direction != Direction.WEST)
            direction = Direction.EAST;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        if (direction != Direction.EAST)
        direction = Direction.WEST;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
        if (isInMenu)
        {
            isInMenu = false;
            repaint();
        }
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
        isInMenu = true;
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}